# function overloading with derived class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, overloading

I have following example. Notice this is just example to illustrate the problem. The real situation is much complex.

The problem is that I must overload function from **base** class. If object used in calculate is type **base** it uses variable x which is common both for base and derived class. If object is of class **derived** it uses its specific variable y. So the real problem is **how to define derived class before class base is defined**.

I know tow workarounds of the problem, but none of them is a solution:

- make class **derived** basic class and loose benefits of inheritance
- change function calculate to `calculate(double y) {return x+y;)` what means like solution but is not due to problem is much complex. Simply I need access to the rest of the object.

```
class base {
protected:
    double x;
public:
    double calculate(base b) {return x+b.x;}
    double calculate(derived d) {return x+d.y;}

}

class derived: base {
public:
    double y;
```

Is this problem resolvable?

thanks in advance...

Comment: You should use virtual functions rather than overloading. You are looking for wrong solution.

Comment: A base class being aware of any of its derived classes is a strong indicator that you should redesign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forward declaring `derived` then defining the bodies of `calculate` out of line after the definition of `derived` should work:

```
class derived;

class base {
protected:
    double x;
public:
    double calculate(base b);
    double calculate(derived d);    
}

class derived: base {
public:
    double y;
};

inline double base::calculate(base b) {return x+b.x;}
inline double base::calculate(derived d) {return x+d.y;}
```

As others have said this could be a poor design with `base` requiring knowledge of `derived`. Maybe `calculate` would be better as a free function:

```
class base {
public:
    double x;    
}

class derived: base {
public:
    double y;
};

inline double calculate(base a, base b) {return a.x+b.x;}
inline double calculate(base a, derived b) {return a.x+b.y;}
```

I've made `x` public to simplify the example, you could make calculate a friend (which would again require knowledge of the `derived` class in `base`) or an an accessor function if you don't want `x` to be public.

A third more idomatic option would be to add a virtual method to get the required value for each class:

```
class base {
protected:
    double x;
    virtual double getValue() const { return x; }
public:
    double calculate(const base& b) { return x + b.getValue(); }
}

class derived: public base {
protected:
    double getValue() override const { return y; }     
private:
    double y;
};
```

Note that `calculate` must take the class by reference to avoid object slicing (and its more efficient).

Depending on your requirements calculate might be better implemented as:

```
double calculate(const base& b) { return getValue() + b.getValue(); }
```

This would mean that `base.calculate(derived)` would return the same result as `derived.calculate(base)`.